# Pip installing required packages, Tensorflow module not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, jupyter

So I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out why my Jupyter program isn't finding Tensorflow. If you see the following error message:

[image: error message from jupyter notebook]

The clear indication is that, in the directory where modules are installed from the code being executed, `/home/jek/.local/python2.7/site-packages`, there's no **Tensorflow**.

The way I have everything installed is using **Anaconda**. From my understanding, each Anaconda environment has its own Python version and own modules, so I created a new environment using:

```
conda create -n tensorflow-environment python=2.7 anaconda
```

Now, I will admit, when installing from the `requirements.txt` I used the following command:

```
(tensorflow-environment) ...:~ pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Which was cause I was getting permission issues + execution issues, and I found this to fix the issue and install all my packages. Once I did this, I ran my jupyter app using `jupyter notebook`, ran the file, and everything worked perfectly fine.

Later, I tried installing the `gpu` version of tensorflow, so I ran the command `pip install tensorflow-gpu --user` to see if that used my GPU instead of CPU, **it didn't**, **it broke everything**, so I tried to uninstall using:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu --user
```

That uninstalled, great, but once I tried to execute my code again, I got the issue that you can see above.

I've tried using all of the following commands in attempt to try and reinstall the packages and fix the issue to how it was before I made this change:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed
```

This reinstalled it all, blah, but I still have the same issue, even after changing environments and attempting to do it again, but it just doesn't go back to what it was.

Could there be something stuck in my path? Leftover files? Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You can check and confirm what packages are installed using `pip freeze`. Does it list tensorflow?

Comment: Awkwardly, yes... https://imgur.com/a/CKxSw @big_bang

Comment: @big_bang I added the code that is being ran to come up with the error.

Comment: That's weird. If it's any env related issue, you can also check installed module in the same jupyter notebook with `help('modules')`. Sorry, can't think of anything else!

Comment: Make sure you  activate and deactive anaconda environment properly before doing such operations. This can be a huge pitfall. Can you activate your environment and can you please paste the output of `conda list` from that environment?